# 24 Word Mnemonic Seed Phrase for Ledger Nano S usable on Trezor?

Tags: security, wallet, cryptocurrency

Can I use my 24-word mnemonic backup seed phrase that was created on my Ledger Nano S on other devices that use a 24-word seed phrase? An example would be the Trezor hardware wallet.

Comment: This question is not about programming.  It would be better asked on https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/ or https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any problem to use same 24 word passphrase on any Wallet, actually 24 words seed phrase is BIP39 mnemonic.

BIP39 seed phrase can be used to regenerate the private key of your wallet , private key can generate the public key and public key is used to generate ethreum address. So this feature is not specific to any wallet(ledger or trezor), it is the property of BIP39 mnemonic to encode the private key of your wallet. That's why you should keep your mnemonic pass phrase secretly .

For further information you can access the link :- https://silentcicero.gitbooks.io/pro-tips-for-ethereum-wallet-management/content/ethereum-wallet-basics/using-seed-phrases-to-create-ethereum-accounts.html

There is an online tool which you can use to regenerate all the information of your wallet using the seed phrase:-https://iancoleman.io/bip39/

Comment: This is mostly true, however, it depends how each app derives their keys. Not every app will use bip32 to derive them so the BIP39 mnemonic might be ignored.

Comment: yes, there are a lot of ways but currently these cryptocurrency wallets specific apps are preferring BIP32 mnemonic as it provides more control to user for keys backup and restoration and it is easy to remember . 
But in real world people forget to keep backup of bip32 mnemonic :) or someone else gets the access to BIP32 written in plain text :)